# How to extend img tag functionality locally on page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

This code makes use of css-filters. When added to the style.css Wordpress file it make all pictures (defined with `<img source="..." ...>`) show up in grayscale, and shows colours when the mouse hovers over. The problem is, that it affects all pictures on the site.
Can this style definition be bound to a certain sidebar?

Comment: `.sidebar img {}`? It all depends on the rest of the page structure. Impossible to give you a correct answer without seeing the HTML. Edit: This is just basic CSS, maybe you should start by researching how CSS selectors work.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.
There is <div class="sidebar" ...> in the interesting area. Yes, I tried .sidebar img {} - but it didn't work.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the relevant HTML markup of the sidebar.

Comment: Solved. That was not enough to reference div class="sidebar", I had to reference another image container div class inside sidebar. Your notices helped, thank you!